# Does wso2 developer studio 3.7.0 supports Wso2 CEP 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep, wso2-integration-studio

As Buckets concept not there in wso2 CEP 3.1.0.
Does wso2 developer studio 3.7.0 supports Wso2 CEP 3.1.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

No. CEP 3.1.0 is not yet supported in Developer studio.

Comment: will it be supported in future?